# How to filter different files from one file 

Tags: awk

Let as say I want different files starting from "process" till next "process.
For example
Input file

```
Process=0
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

Process=1
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
Process=2
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
```

Expected output
File_0 should contain

```
Process=0
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
```

File_1 should contain

```
Process=1
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
```

File_2 should contain

```
Process=2
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Write clearly and simply.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [csplit](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=c/csplit) command in Linux. It *splits* text files at delimiters (which may be defined by a regular expression).

Answer (score 2):

This creates the files for each section and outputs the text to them. If there is text before the first "Process" then it is put in a file called "Preamble".

```
awk -F '[ =]' 'BEGIN {file="Preamble"} {if ($1 == "Process") file="File_"$2; print >> file}' inputfile
```

Comment: Nice use of FS.  It could be rewritten as: `awk -F '[ =]' 'BEGIN {file="Preamble"} $1 == "Process" {file="File_"$2} {print >> file}' inputfile`

Answer (score 1):

use gawk/nawk(Solaris)

```
gawk -F"=" '/Process/{f=1;n=$2;print $0 > "File_"n;next}
f && /Process/{f=0} 
f&&NF{print $0 > "File_"n}
' file
```